# Change input fields to a different color when there is an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have setup a php login page using bootstrap. I want to change the input fields to red when the fields are left empty, invalid email, or username is already in use. Currently when the user clicks register it opens a new page with these messages.

How do I just change the input fields to red and display the message in the input field?

Here is my PHP code:

```
require("config.php");
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user fills out fields 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { die("Please enter a username."); }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); }  
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { die("Please enter a password."); } 

    // Check if the username is already taken
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container hero-unit">        
<div class="row" style="margin-top:20px">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
        <form action="register.php" method="post" role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>Please Register</h2>
                <hr class="colorgraph">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-facebook btn-block"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> &nbsp;Sign in with Facebook</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> &nbsp;Sign in with Twiter</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-or">
                    <hr class="hr-or">
                    <span class="span-or">or</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="username" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <hr class="colorgraph">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Register" /> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block">Sign In</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need anything else from me please let me know

Comment: Because you need to check against your username database, you will need to query your server.  If you don't want to change pages, you will need to do this via AJAX.  Basically, make a background call to your PHP, and don't allow your form to submit until you get a positive response from your server.  If you haven't done any AJAX, I would suggest reading through a few tutorials.

Comment: title is the input attribute containing the text that advises about the input, :invalid is the CSS psudeo-class that targets problematic inputs. you should also use <input type=email> and _required_ attribs as needed. the password could use a regexp to define validity by putting it in the _pattern_ attrib of an input

Comment: Just a comment, but you can't use `die`, unless you want to kill the entire php page.

Comment: so should i remove die from the code? Not sure what I should be doing here. Should i use javascipt? if so will that effect the php check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using a plugin that I found here:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Powerful-Form-Validation-Plugin-For-jQuery-Bootstrap-3.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [jquery validate documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)
you need to call the validate method on the form.

```
<script>
$("#formId").validate();
</script>
```

Comment: is this the best way of doing it or can I modify the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the complete solution to this will be pretty long and based on more than we know at the moment. If I understood you correct, the check should be done when the form is submitted (before leaving the page). This requires AJAX.

Based on your php script for validation above, I assume that it will just echo anything if there is an error in the validation. Based on that assumption, you could do something like this...

First, let's start with the form.
Add an onsubmit-listener to the form-tag:

`<form action="register.php" method="post" role="form" onsubmit="return validate_data()">`

Second, add a javascript function to handle the AJAX request:

`<script type="text/javascript">
      function validate_data()
      {
        signupRequest = $.ajax({
            url:    "path/to/your/php/validation/page",
            type:   "post",
            data:   { 'username': $('#email').val(), "password": $('#password').val() }
        })
        .done(function(s) {
            if (s == '') {
                // Validation looks ok, login the created user, move on using e.g. top.location.href or do whatever you want... :)
            } else {
                var el = $('#email');
                $(el).addClass('has_error');
                $(el).val(s);
        })
        .fail(function(obj, s) {
            alert( "error: " + s);
        });
        // Make sure that the form does not submit (we want to stay on this page)
        return false;
      }
    </script>`

This was just written out of the air, so there may be some typos or so - But hopefully you get the idea... ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, you can also add a pure javascript validation like dss suggested above. However, you should never fully trust a javascript validation since they easily can be manipulated by evil users. Always run a secondary validation on the server-side before actually inserting/updating data in your database. By using an AJAX call for the php validation instead of jQuerys built-in validation, you can reuse that same validation script for the server-side when you want to play around with the data (on the server side).

Comment: I have tried so many different JavaScript solutions and it continues to open a new page with the PHP error.